# How can I make my php script to email me in the future without anyone visiting my website or using cron?

Tags: php, web

I want to write a php script that emails me on a specific date and time without anyone visiting the website or using cron.

I have a web hosting without cron and I'm wondering if it is possible to make a script for, for example a newsletter, to email someone automatically in the future?

Any help?  Thx!!

Comment: I suggest you to take in mind that if you send a big amount of mails via PHP almost every service like gmail, or outlook can mark your mails as spam. This is why you could need a service like mailchimp. If you only need to send one mail there is no need to use an external service.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you have a webpage that uses AJAX requests to mail you. But that would require leaving that web page up indefinitely. Unless I'm mistake, I'm unaware of any software to do this.

PHP can't email you without something provoking it (cron job or user visiting a webpage)

Comment: Yeah Fabian and tdoggy, I guess I will have to learn cron (and get a webhosting that has cron implemented), use a batch file to visit my website regularry or get enough users of my website.

Answer (score 1):

How should this happen? When there is no input to the server, how should the server know, that he has to do something?

This is exactly for which is cron: Periodically a script/program is started and this script can then do stuff (check the date, etc.).

Another trigger would be a visit to the site, where the script could check, if your date is reached and then do something.

One option left, a script which runs forever and checks periodically, if the time is reached. My guess is that this is not possible on your host, as the execution time is normally fixed to a maximum amount of time. (To prevent unintended loops and other things)

To conclude this: No, there is actually no way on a shared host, which do not allow cron jobs.